# Какие языки программирования больше всего подходят для мат.вычеслений?

Tags: математика, любой-язык, длинная-арифметика

Я знаю что в Python хорошо реализованна длинная арифметика. Есть ли ещё подобные языки?

Comment: А какое отношение *"мат.вычесления"* имеют к длинной арифметике?...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: FORTRAN — язык именно для математики :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Длинная арифметика уже встроена в язык **Java**, но не присутствует в других языках: **C++**, **C#**(в framework 4.0 появился **BigInteger**) или **Pascal**.